# Software Required for the remote installation of Windows

Tags: installation

I have around 15 computers in my lab but its very painful when i have to install the windows one bye one when needed. So i want to know is there any system that i can use so that i can install the windows remotely from a master computer.

I have heard about Norton Ghost can do that but i am not sure.. So can somebody suggest on this.

Thx in advance..

Comment: I think you should ask this question on ServerFault.

Comment: anyway I recommend http://www.acronis.com/enterprise/products/snapdeploy/

Comment: Can your machine PXE boot?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a windows server to look after these clients then I'd suggest [Windows Deployment Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772106%28WS.10%29.aspx), which is included in Windows Server.

Failing that, I'd consider [FOG](http://www.fogproject.org/), which is a very decent open source alternative. Both can be a no cost/low cost  thing to set up depending on what you already have.

Comment: Vote++.  WDS is very good, and can be combined with DFS to provide "load balanced" installation points.

Comment: +1.  WDS works well if you're already running Windows Servers.  If not, I have had success with FOG as well.  It should be noted that both solutions require PXE booting your computers.

Answer (score 0):

if you are installing operating systems, and have the hardware to support it [PXE booting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preboot_Execution_Environment) is the way to go, you can maintain installation images on a single server, boot from the media using pxe and away you go

Comment: Windows Deployment Services is a PXE system...

Comment: @Simon Catlin Thanks for the clarification Simon, I do not work with windows my self, hence mentioning the PXE option.